# Drag force and coefficient for cylinder through water

Tags: drag

Pushing a cylinder through the water with an angular velocity of $\omega$.

[image]

The cylinder diameter and length are $D$ and $L$ respectively and the length from the rotation point to the center of the cylinder is $L_{arm}$.

$F_D = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \rho \cdot C_D \cdot A \cdot v^2 $

But how do I find the drag coefficient?

Comment: By experiment is a possibility.

Comment: I don't have that possibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tables for common shapes, e.g. in my fluid mechanics formulary I find for a long cylinder $C_\text{D}=0.3 \dots 1.3$ depending on the Re-Number.